# Simple horizontal slides

Tags: presentations

What is the simplest way to make a slide presentation? I tried [`beamer`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer), but it is really complicated and I would like to have the same simple look as in *slides*, but horizontal rather than vertical.

Answer (score 1):

Uhm...

```
\documentclass[landscape,letterpaper,pdftex]{slides}
```

does `landscape` not work for you?

---

I keep meaning to learn one of the newer presentation classes, but I have this well developed set of tools I use with `slides` and it never seem worth the effort *just now, for this talk*...

Comment: I am using MikTeX portable with TeXworks. It doesn't seem to notice the lanscape option.

Comment: @Trevis: I'm afraid I'm stuck then.

Comment: I've sometimes found that to get things to go landscape, I need to include `\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}`. That will alter margins, etc, too, but you can set them back to what you want in the options to geometry. Use the layout package to easily find most relevant lengths.

Answer (score 0):

the [prosper class](http://texcatalogue.sarovar.org/entries/prosper.html) maybe

You can customize Beamer as much as you wish to get "simple horizontal" slides

Comment: I couldn't get beamer from the random repository when compiling from TeXworks with MikTeX portable. Beamer works in TeXword but I dislike the interphase, I never use it, I always worked in TeXnic Center with MiKtex, but I cannot install it at the moment, so i've been using the portable MiKtex.

Answer (score 0):

Also consider [`powerdot`](http://ctan.org/pkg/powerdot).